# How to simplify nested JavaScript loops

Tags: javascript

I have written three `for` loops for displaying data on the screen using JavaScript. How can I simplify the following code?

My Json Format:

```js
    {
        "result": {
            "type": "SUCCESS",
            "data": [{          
                "monthName": "July",
                "monthId": 7,
                "weeks": [{             
                    "days": [{                  
                        "day": "Sunday",
                        "date": "07/31/2016"
                    }],             
                }],
            }],
        }
    }
```

```js
var monthObj = response.result.data;

for (var i = 0; i < monthObj.length; i++) {  
  for (var t = 0; t < monthObj[i].weeks.length; t++) {
    for (var s = 0; s < monthObj[i].weeks[t].days.length; s++) {
    }
  }     
}
```

This is my loop, here I have written 3 loops.
Is there any easy way to simplify these loops?

Comment: Can you also add the code that displays the data?

Comment: Why do you imagine it might be simplifiable? How do you want to simplify it? Is there some reason you did not add the for-loop tag to this question?

Comment: i have written 3 for loops, My doubt is this possible to write everything in one for loop.

Comment: @AhmadIbrahim Please do not remove the jQuery tag. It expresses the OP's willingness to entertain a jQuery solution.

Comment: Since years/months/days are more or less static data, the only dynamic data you need is the date, so your data might as well be `"data" : ["07/31/2016"]`, which can give you all the other info when converted to a Date object. It would reduce everything down to one loop. (depending on what you're doing with those dates...)

Answer (score 2):

It depends how your data looks like and what you want to do inside the loop. If you expect to have more than one entry for `month`, `week` and `day` and you want to perform some action on all of them, you will need three loops.

I'd recommend using [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) instead of `for` though:

```js
const data = {
  "result": {
    "type": "SUCCESS",
    "data": [{
      "monthName": "July",
      "monthId": 7,
      "weeks": [{
        "days": [{
          "day": "Sunday",
          "date": "07/31/2016"
        }],
      }],
    }],
  }
}

data.result.data.forEach(month => {
  month.weeks.forEach(week => {
    week.days.forEach(day => console.log(day))
  })
})
```